# Seeding user with int ids fails in Asp.net core MVC6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I am using Identity 3. I want to seed an admin user on startup.

I have converted the string ids to "int" ids using as an example [SwiftCourier](https://github.com/jayrulez/SwiftCourier) on github. Identity 3 is different in some aspects and this applies to the setting of "int" for ids as shown in the SwiftCourier example as compared to [Identity 2](http://johnatten.com/2014/07/13/asp-net-identity-2-0-extending-identity-models-and-using-integer-keys-instead-of-strings/) and the setting of "int" ids.

I've done this by placing "int" after my user:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<int>{...}
```

After my Role:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<int>
```

and in startup.cs in configuration services I entered this:

```
            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(options => options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<JobsDbContext, int>()
            .AddUserStore<UserStore<User, Role, JobsDbContext, int>>()
            .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<Role, JobsDbContext, int>>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

I then used this to seed roles and it works with integer ids:

```
public static void EnsureRolesCreated(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<JobsDbContext>();
        if (context.AllMigrationsApplied())
        {
            var roleManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RoleManager<Role>>();

            var Roles = new List<Role>();

            Roles.Add(new Role { Name = "Admin", Description = "Users able to access all areas" });
            Roles.Add(new Role { Name = "Technician", Description = "Users able to access just the schedule" });

            foreach (var role in Roles)
            {
                if (!roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(role.Name.ToUpper()).Result)
                {
                    roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So far so good... I want to seed just one admin user to start with and this is where I fail...

I have used the following Stackoverflow [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343599/how-to-seed-users-and-roles-with-code-first-migration-using-identity-asp-net-mvc) by @Guy.

I am struggling with UserStore with this line:

```
await new UserStore<User>(context).CreateAsync(userWithRoles.User);
```

It fails on "User" which is my ApplicationUser just renamed.

The error I get is:

```
The type 'JobsLedger.Models.Identity.User' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore<TUser>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'JobsLedger.Models.Identity.User' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser<string>'.
```

It seems to be complaining on the fact that the id is "int" I think

How do I make the UserStore work with an "int"in this regard?? Its set to int in the Startup.cs as shown above..

If I have to create a custom "UserStore" that works with "int".. how do you do it in Identity 3?

Comment: I gave an example of adding the user to roles, did it help? If it did then pls mark the answer as right answer

Comment: I have just done that.  I cant get the user to be created here using int ids let alone add roles to the user.. its failing on userstore..

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the most elegant solution but this works...

My aim was to seed an admin user and also to be added to the admin role. I have managed this while avoiding using UserStoreand with integer IDs.

```
using JobsLedger.DAL;
using JobsLedger.Models.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;

namespace JobsLedger.Models.Seeding
{
    public static class SeedAdminUser
    {
        public static async void EnsureAdminUserCreated(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            var context = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<JobsDbContext>();
            if (context.AllMigrationsApplied())
            {
                var userManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<UserManager<User>>();
                var roleManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RoleManager<Role>>();

                var user = new User
                {
                    UserName = "Admin",
                    NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN",
                    Email = "Email@email.com",
                    NormalizedEmail = "email@email.com",
                    EmailConfirmed = true,
                    LockoutEnabled = false,
                    SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
                };

                var password = new PasswordHasher<User>();
                var hashed = password.HashPassword(user, "password");
                user.PasswordHash = hashed;

                var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, user.PasswordHash);

                var AdminUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("Admin");

                if (AdminUser != null)
                {
                    if (roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin").Result)
                    {
                        var RoleResult = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(AdminUser, "Admin");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also placed this entry into the StartUp.cs class after "app.UseIdentity();":

```
app.EnsureAdminUserCreated();
```

...Models.Identity has the "User" class in it and thats why its included in "using".

You will also need to add the following to make this work:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
```

Finally you will need roles to already be added as per the question above..