# Seed Roles (RoleManager vs RoleStore)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-migrations

Through looking at the posts here, I've seen two different ways of creating ASP.NET Identity roles through Entity Framework seeding. One way uses `RoleManager` and the other uses `RoleStore`. I was wondering if there is a difference between the two. As using the latter will avoid one less initialization

```
string[] roles = { "Admin", "Moderator", "User" };

// Create Role through RoleManager

var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

foreach (string role in roles)
{
    if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
    {
       manager.Create(new IdentityRole(role));
    }

// Create Role through RoleStore

var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);

foreach (string role in roles)
{
    if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == role))
    {
       roleStore.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(role));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, using both methods, you achieve the same results.

But, the **correct** usage would be:

```cs
var context = new ApplicationIdentityDbContext();
var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

string[] roles = { "Admin", "Moderator", "User" };

foreach (string role in roles)
{
     if (!roleManager.RoleExists(role))
     {
           roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole(role));
     }
}
```

The `RoleManager` is a wrapper over a `RoleStore`, so when you are adding roles to the **manager**, you are actually inserting them in the **store**, but the difference here is that the `RoleManager` can implement a custom `IIdentityValidator<TRole>` **role validator**.

So, implementing the **validator**, each time you add a **role** through the **manager**, it will first be validated before being added to the **store**.