How to remove PasswordHash Autogeneration when seeding Identity NET CORE
I'm seeding the User identity table using EF core configurations, this is my method.
  public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IdentityUser> builder)
  {
    var hasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();
    var adminUser = new IdentityUser
    {
      Id = Id,
      UserName = AdminUserName,
      NormalizedUserName = AdminUserName,
      Email = AdminUserName,
      NormalizedEmail = AdminUserName,
      EmailConfirmed = true,
      ConcurrencyStamp = ConcurrencyStamp,
      SecurityStamp = SecurityStamp
    };

    adminUser.PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(adminUser, Password);
    
    builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);
    builder.Property(u => u.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
    builder.Property(u => u.ConcurrencyStamp).ValueGeneratedNever();
    builder.Property(u => u.PasswordHash).ValueGeneratedNever();
    builder.Property(u => u.SecurityStamp).ValueGeneratedNever();

    builder.HasData(adminUser);
  }

It works great when creating the first migration, applying all the fields i listed in the code.
The issue arises when i create a second migration (even without changing anything), it always create a migration trying to change the password hash, even if i specified to never generate the value.
 public partial class UserAndRoleSeed3 : Migration
 {
     /// <inheritdoc />
     protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
     {
         migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
             schema: "Users",
             table: "AspNetUsers",
             keyColumn: "Id",
             keyValue: "0fbad743-9b2c-4eac-aa17-957880a5465d",
             column: "PasswordHash",
             value: "AQAAAAIAAYagAAAAELfdYk76pRqQjoKQM9cOrCEplDXzB2mFhQdaCByEIBU4ng6fb9FtK7rY6sCLKwhS8A==");
     }

     /// <inheritdoc />
     protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
     {
         migrationBuilder.UpdateData(
             schema: "Users",
             table: "AspNetUsers",
             keyColumn: "Id",
             keyValue: "0fbad743-9b2c-4eac-aa17-957880a5465d",
             column: "PasswordHash",
             value: "AQAAAAIAAYagAAAAELG0nqfYzxLsa3gKh8PlUIx23oUZOe4RJjrk1DRPSdYvdkDqoQsTVhCApmGOx0awVw==");
     }
 }

How can i avoid this issue with migrations? Thanks

Check this out, this helped me with this exact problem recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34343599/how-to-seed-users-and-roles-with-code-first-migration-using-identity-asp-net-cor

Already read that post but sadly no-one is getting the issue i'm describing here.
